# Как отправить проект из Android Studio в репозиторий GitHub?

Tags: android-studio, github

В Android Studio получается создать новый репозиторий на GitHub, но не могу разобратся, как отправить весь проект.

Получаю такую ошибку при попытке отправки:

> remote: Repository not found. fatal: repository 'github.com/Nersomy/ghp_RIfp<...>YV.git' not found

Comment: И что вы пробовали? Ничего не понятно

Comment: Создовал и спомощью токена и авторизации делал и по всяким инструкциям пытался сделать ((( Имею такую ошибку припопытке отправки - remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/Nersomy/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.git/' not found

Comment: Ошибка означает, что репозиторий не найден. Вы уверены что у вас на гитхабе https://github.com/Nersomy есть репозиторий с таким длинным именем `ghp_RIfp...YV`? Среди публичных репозиториев такого нет. Проверьте название вашего репозитория, возможно, вы хотели использовать репозиторий https://github.com/Nersomy/android_app_test.git?

Comment: Слона-то я и не заметил ) Огромное спасибо!!!